# Angular blur event preventing click event of a button

Tags: angular, onblur

I have a nested child component that contains an input. There is a `blur` event on the input

```html
<input (blur)="onBlur()" ...>
```

In an ancestor component I have another element with a click event

```html
<button (click)="onClick() ...>
```

Due to the `blur` event, the `click` event doesn't fire.

I can fix this by changing the `click` event to a `mousedown`. This isn't ideal because the user experience changes slightly.

I've tried adding a `event.preventDefault();` method in the `onBlur()` method, but it doesn't seem to achieve anything (despite me reading on other SO posts that it would fix it).

Are there any fixes for this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-h8vgrf?file=src%2Fdeeply-nested%2Fdeeply-nested.component.html

Comment: inside onBlur check the related target. If its not input then return false.

event.relatedtarget

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget

Comment: @cfprabhu I console logged the onBlur event and the relatedTarget property was null.

Comment: @Vega I added event.StopPropogatation() to my onBlur callback and nothing happened.

Comment: @Vega in the Angular app that I'm working on, the child app is a deeply nested, reused component, so I don't think I can simply make the changes you suggest. I need to keep the input (blur) event.

I think the current design/intent of the component simply isn't very good. But I'm trying to fix a bug as best I can without making too many changes.

Comment: @NarenMurali The way you phrased your comment suggest that creating and linking a stackblitz would be sufficient. However, posting something only on stackblitz is not sufficient, the question itself should contain the [mre]. Offsite links like to stackblitz can be used for supporting information, but does not free the OP from including the necessary code in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is working fine, when you add a new element using `blur` the button is shifted down and the click is not recorded.

One more problem I saw was the click was not wrapped in event binding `(click)` which prevented the click from happening.

html

```
<span (click)="clearAll($event)">X - Clear All</span><br /><br />
<app-deeply-nested [inputFormCtrl]="formControl"></app-deeply-nested>

<br />
<br />
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, UntypedFormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { DeeplyNestedComponent } from '../deeply-nested/deeply-nested.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ancestor',
  templateUrl: './ancestor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ancestor.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [DeeplyNestedComponent],
})
export class AncestorComponent implements OnInit {
  formControl: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: UntypedFormBuilder) {
    this.formControl = this.fb.group({
      tags: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  clearAll(event: Event) {
    this.formControl.reset();
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8abynf?file=src%2Fdeeply-nested%2Fdeeply-nested.component.ts,src%2Fancestor%2Fancestor.component.ts,src%2Fancestor%2Fancestor.component.html,src%2Fglobal_styles.css)

Comment: @Vega The button is shifted down every time a new element gets added, that is the root cause, I wont close because of this!

Comment: Ohhh, brilliant spot! Yes that is indeed the bug that we had on our website. Thanks so much!